# iframe causing duplicate landmark roles

Tags: html, iframe, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm tasked with taking a website and making it so that the AInspector Sidebar evaluates to at least no WAI ARIA violations (preferably no warnings either).

There is a page that includes embedded Vimeo video(s). Included in the code that the iframe brings in is an element with the landmark role "contentinfo", which I am already using in the appropriate place on the website pages. So now I have a violation for duplicate landmark roles.

Is there a good way to solve this? I guess I could use the "old embed code" offered by Vimeo but I'd rather avoid that if at all possible. I've searched all over but can't find any guidelines or best practices for this sort of situation. Maybe I'm not using the right terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#contentinfo

While the spec does say

> "Within any document or application, the author SHOULD mark no more
>   than one element with the contentinfo role."

it also says

> "Note: Because document and application elements can be nested in the
>   DOM, they may have multiple contentinfo elements as DOM descendants,
>   assuming each of those is associated with different document nodes,
>   either by a DOM nesting (e.g., document within document) or by use of
>   the aria-owns attribute."

So perhaps if your iframe was a document or application, that would satisfy the tool.  If not, then the tool might be interpreting the spec incorrectly.